# How to load multiple audio files into web audio API context with a single async call?

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest, fetch, web-audio-api

I'd like to load multiple mp3/ogg files from the server into Web-audio-api with a single call.
I know that the for / loop below doesn't work, how do I get this going?

```
    var AudioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var AudioBufferArr = [];
    
    for (let fileNumber = 1; fileNumber <= 4; fileNumber++) fetch_audiodata_from_server(fileNumber);
        
    function fetch_audiodata_from_server(fileNumber) {
        fetch("inc/postrequest.php",{
            method: 'POST',
            body: 'fileNumber=' + encodeURIComponent(fileNumber),
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buffer => {
            AudioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer, function(decodedData) {
                AudioBufferArr[fileNumber] = decodedData;
            })
        });
    }
```

Thanks and cheers,
Rob

Comment: What makes you assume the requests are not done concurrently? All what is missing is properly waiting for all of them to have finished.

Comment: @Bergi, yup, i was impatient ... I hate browser cache when I'm debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be if you just asked the server once. But if you insist of doing several Api calls you can use Promise all.

Note this is not a working example just an idea how you can use Promise All

```
let promiseList = [];
for (let fileNumber = 1; fileNumber <= 4; fileNumber++) {
  promiseList.push(fetchDataFromServer(fileNumber));
}

Promise.all(promiseList).then((values) => {
  //   *magic to the returned values*
});

function fetchDataFromServer(fileNr) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch( ...insert code here...)
      .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then((buffer) => {
           *more code with the buffer*
           resolve(*the data you want to return*)
      });
  });
}
```